# Installing mysql installed other software and changed icon set

Tags: pi-3, web-server, server, mysql

Raspberry Pi 3 running NOOBS with Raspbian Pixel installed.

So i'm trying to setup a webserver on my Raspberry Pi 3 and did that. Then i  added MySQL.

Running `sudo aptitude install mysql-server php5-mysql` installed unwanted software, uninstalled wanted software, and changed icon-set to Raspbian Jessie (non Pixel version). Also whenever i click a taskbar item (other than menu button) it gives me a error: `/usr/share/raspi-ui-overrides/applications/geany.desktop: No such file or directory`. Where `geany` is that is where whatever software i try to run name is.

How do i undo this without reinstalling my system?? Please help!

UPDATE 2-11-2017:

It will not boot into the desktop after rebooting. I used raspi-config to enabled booting into desktop by default, then rebooted. Nothing. No desktop or terminal. After sshing into my pi, enabling booting into CLI (I think that's what it's called), then rebooted. Now back at the terminal. Typing startx doesn't work. So know my desktop is gone!!

Comment: What unwanted software did it install?

Comment: a bunch. I don't know what it all installed.

Comment: @Jacobm001, please see updated question.